# Solving AXB=C equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I would like some help with finding $X$ for the equation $AX B=C$. I understand how to get $X$ by itself ($X=A^{-1}AXBB^{-1}=A^{-1}CB^{-1}$) and I have found the inverse for $B$. The problem is that I can't find the inverse of $A$ which I think is inconsistent. The answer is supposed to be a parameter solution. Here are the matrices:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    6 & -2 \\
    -3 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    -7 & -3 \\
    -2 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
    28 & 12 \\
    -14 & -6 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$
$$Answer=\begin{bmatrix}
    -2/3+s/3 & t/3 \\
    s & t \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Indeed, the inverse of $A$ doesn't exist.  So, you should have it to the point that $AX=CB^{-1}$.  Now... let $X=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and explicitly write out the result of the multiplication.  You can then describe this using a system of four linear equations with four unknowns... a situation that you should know very well how to do in a linear algebra course.

Comment: Let $X=[x_1,x_2]$ and $CB^{-1}=[y_1,y_2]$. Then $AXB=C$ is equivalent to $Ax_1=y_1$ and $Ax_2=y_2$. So, basically, you are just solving two systems of linear equations.

Answer (score -1):

You can check that $A$ is not invertible, because its determinant is $6\times 1 - (-2)\times(-3) = 0$.
This is why you cannot find an inverse for $A$, and also why your answer features parameters $s$ and $t$.

Notice that, as you yourself showed in the opening question, if $A$ and $B$ were both invertible then the answer would be unique $($that is, it would not depend on the value of some parameters$)$.